# Multivariate Itô's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

Hey guys I'm looking for worked examples who show how to apply Itô's lemma in several variables, starting from the very basics. Thank you in advance!

Comment: From any textbook on stochastic calculus, such as that of Oksendal, you can find such examples.

Comment: I've had a look at Oksendal, but there are worked examples only about the 1-dimensional case!

Comment: See example 4.2.2, exercuise 4.6 b),  and example, 8.5.8, in the 5th edition

Comment: see Chapter 11 of my book the Concepts and Practice...

Comment: The multi-version is very similar, just that we need to take into the covariance into account. In a single-dimension, those covariances are zero.